# How can I further analyze ram usage in a possible leak? [debian@HyperV + Kafka + Zookeeper]

Tags: debian, hyper-v, memory, kafka, zookeeper

We have a 3-box cluster Kafka+Zookeeper, in a virtualized enviroment (in Windows 2019 HyperV).

In the machines' config dynamic memory is disabled, and they have 4G RAM each (I know it's a very few amount for this kind of cluster, but the usage is very light)

- Guest SO is Debian stretch 9.3, kernel 4.9.0-5-amd64
- Kafka is 2.11-2.3.0
- Zookeeper is 3.4.9

Once you start the cluster or restart a node, ram usage it's normal:

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3937        2200         198          40        1538        1462
Swap:          1903           0        1903
```

After a week ram usage gets normalized (50% ram usage).
But after 2 weeks starts to drain ram slowly.
Until a few days later when physical free percent reaches 15, that's when it falls sharply (and quickly), starting to eat swap until it gets completely allocated.

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3937        3744         117           3          76          39
Swap:          1903        1197         706
```

I've installed smem and here you can see the difference between both situations:

(NOTE: **right and wrong are different machines**, but config and behavior over the time are the same)

```
RIGHT:
# smem -tw
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0
kernel image                      0          0          0
kernel dynamic memory       2777144    1983260     793884
userspace memory            1027116      44548     982568
free memory                  228016     228016          0
----------------------------------------------------------
                            4032276    2255824    1776452

WRONG:
# smem -tw
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0
kernel image                      0          0          0
kernel dynamic memory       2763772      64968    2698804
userspace memory            1138972      35928    1103044
free memory                  129532     129532          0
----------------------------------------------------------
                            4032276     230428    3801848
```

Most of the memory is in kernel dynamic memory/Noncache, I'm not sure what it implies nor the reason.

Through the monitoring we've seen that (in /etc/meminfo):

- DirectMap4k grows
- MemFree decreases sharply when it starts to eat swap
- MemAvailable decreases slowly
- Most of the other ones decrease

**Here's a pic of our monitoring tool:**

[image: Here's a pic of our monitoring tool]

Adding all processes' Ram/Swap:

```
RIGHT:
# for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk -F ' ' '/VmRSS/ {print $2}' $file; done | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum/1024 "Mb"}'
1053.5Mb
# for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk -F ' ' '/VmSwap/ {print $2}' $file; done | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum/1024 "Mb"}'
0Mb

WRONG:
# for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk -F ' ' '/VmRSS/ {print $2}' $file; done | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum/1024 "Mb"}'
308.941Mb
# for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk -F ' ' '/VmSwap/ {print $2}' $file; done | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum/1024 "Mb"}'
1147.54Mb
```

top -c, sorted by Mem:

```
RIGHT:
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   674 kafka     20   0 17.229g 818152  19956 S  12.1 20.3   3304:07 java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesCo+
   734 zookeep+  20   0 4838708 172708  16736 S   0.0  4.3  81:41.62 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zooke+
   676 Debian-+  20   0   58368  10636   6236 S   0.0  0.3  16:08.80 /usr/sbin/snmpd -LSwd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -p /run/snmpd.pid -f
     1 root      20   0   57124   6900   5320 S   0.0  0.2  34:29.32 /sbin/init
116398 root      20   0   95168   6812   5840 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.34 sshd: root@pts/0

WRONG:
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  2732 kafka     20   0 17.269g 235004      0 S   6.9  5.8   1259:50 java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesCo+
   707 root      20   0 1955516  20720   6896 S   2.8  0.5  52:04.15 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -environment systemd -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /et+
  2537 zookeep+  20   0 4437272   8944      0 S   0.0  0.2  20:29.38 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zooke+
     1 root      20   0   57292   3688   2704 S   0.0  0.1  29:28.41 /sbin/init
```

This being said, I would appreciate if anyone could point me how to get more evidences to locate the root cause of this.

Thank you.

Edit (2020/06/26 Add some outputs):

```sh
RIGHT:
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4032276 kB
MemFree:          155480 kB
MemAvailable:    1925864 kB
Buffers:          679696 kB
Cached:          1293012 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2013308 kB
Inactive:         985748 kB
Active(anon):     867464 kB
Inactive(anon):   200204 kB
Active(file):    1145844 kB
Inactive(file):   785544 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1949692 kB
SwapFree:        1949692 kB
Dirty:               160 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1026380 kB
Mapped:            49320 kB
Shmem:             41332 kB
Slab:             129624 kB
SReclaimable:      81024 kB
SUnreclaim:        48600 kB
KernelStack:        6592 kB
PageTables:         5936 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3965828 kB
Committed_AS:    1151652 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     1368000 kB
DirectMap2M:     2826240 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB

# ps -ef | grep java
kafka       674      1 10 Jun03 ?        2-09:20:08 java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/opt/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/opt/kafka/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/kafka/bin/../config/log4j.properties -cp /opt/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2.3.0-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.11-3.9.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/spotbugs-annotations-3.1.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.11.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.0-1.jar kafka.Kafka /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
zookeep+    734      1  0 Jun03 ?        01:28:30 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg


WRONG:
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4032276 kB
MemFree:          141820 kB
MemAvailable:     170960 kB
Buffers:          104896 kB
Cached:           150488 kB
SwapCached:       129780 kB
Active:          1872244 kB
Inactive:         798372 kB
Active(anon):    1709660 kB
Inactive(anon):   746052 kB
Active(file):     162584 kB
Inactive(file):    52320 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1949692 kB
SwapFree:        1412724 kB
Dirty:                72 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2286048 kB
Mapped:            39720 kB
Shmem:             40468 kB
Slab:              72456 kB
SReclaimable:      31544 kB
SUnreclaim:        40912 kB
KernelStack:        8360 kB
PageTables:         9968 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3965828 kB
Committed_AS:    4008680 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     3798976 kB
DirectMap2M:      395264 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB

# ps -ef | grep java
zookeep+   2537      1  0 Jun08 ?        00:23:35 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
kafka      2732      1  5 Jun08 ?        22:06:19 java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/opt/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/opt/kafka/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/kafka/bin/../config/log4j.properties -cp /opt/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.9.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.18.v20190429.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2.3.0-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.11-3.9.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/spotbugs-annotations-3.1.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.11.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.0-1.jar kafka.Kafka /opt/kafka/config/server.properties

For ease of view (kafka's params) :
-Xmx2048m
-Xms512m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Xloggc:/opt/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10
-XX:GCLogFileSize=100M
```

I'm not sure if the Java mem's values are optimal for this scenario, but I tried to configure them a bit restrained.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` and `ps -ef |grep java`. I want to see the memory allocation on those 2 systems and the java memory parameters, like `-Xmx`, which limits the maximum size of the Java Heap.